# ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8 not booting

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8 without any problems.

But when I start my system, windows 8 boots up without even asking which os I want to use.

Why is this happening and how can I rectify it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, the problem was that when my PC booted, it was booting straight into UEFI boot-loader without an Ubuntu option rather than Grub2. 
I tried two possible solutions:

- The first was to follow the instructions at the end of [this page on adding Ubuntu as an option to the boot-loader](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/2/), the part about EasyBCD is the one I'm talking about. This worked for a while in my case but then for some reason it stopped working after an update and my Ubuntu entry didn't do anything anymore.
- The second which has worked for me since is to boot via USB into a Linux session and use boot-repair:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install boot-repair
> ```
>
> Using boot-repair I was able to fix my issue as it does all the work for you. I'd suggest going straight for this option as it worked flawlessly for me.

*Note:* [All credit for the second fix goes to Luis Alvarado for his work on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system/228069#228069)

Answer (score 0):

May be you installed ubuntu manually.
I mean that you must have made the partitions on the disk by yourself and may be you didn't install the boot loader.
Check your installation again.
Check in windows 8 whether the drive is partitioned or not.

Comment: I didn't do anything to the partition. The installation suggested that I install ubuntu alongside windows8 and divided the space 235 gb for windows and 220 gb for linux